# try catch block not working

Tags: matlab, try-catch

Might anyone know why this try catch block loop is not working. I want the code to go to the catch block whenever the user inputs a string instead of a number but it doesn't seem to want to.

```
x = 1;
while x == 1
    try
        degree = input('Please enter the degree of the polynomial of interest: ');
        if degree > 0 && degree <= 4
            x = 0;
        else
            disp('Please Enter a degree from 1 to 4')
        end
    catch
        exit = input('do you wish to exit (Y/N)','s');
        if strcmp(exit,'Y')
            break
        else
            disp('Please enter an integer this time')
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't know if a `try catch` block is the best way to achieve what you're trying to do. I would say take in a string, use `str2num` to convert it to a number. The function also returns a state flag to tell you if the conversion succeeded or not. Then you can loop on that. Check here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html

Comment: You call your `input()` inside the `try/catch`, shouldn't you call it before the `try/catch` and use the `try/catch` to verify that it is an integer? (e.g. using `mod(degree,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've also got to detect the error condition (for example, if the input degree is not an integer) and throw an exception of type MException to be caught by the catch block.

Something like:

```
x = 1;
while x == 1
    try
        degree = input('Please enter the degree of the polynomial of interest: ');
        if ~isa(degree,'integer')
           ME = MException('MyFunction:notInteger', ...
           'Variable %s not an integer',degree);
           throw(ME)
        end
        if degree > 0 && degree <= 4
            x = 0;
        else
            disp('Please Enter a degree from 1 to 4')
        end
    catch ME
        exit = input('do you wish to exit (Y/N)','s');
        if strcmp(exit,'Y')
            break
        else
            disp('Please enter an integer this time')
        end
    end
end
```

You may want additional logic in your catch block to do something with the caught exception depending on the specifics of your problem.